# Auto generate method comment in Xcode

Tags: xcode, methods, comments

Is there a way in Xcode to generate method comment automatically similar to what you do in Eclipse for javadoc comments.

For example press you may hit /** one row before a method declaration and eclipse automatically generates the skeleton of method comments.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use the Code Snippets library for this. It won't automatically generate placeholders for each parameter, but it's pretty useful nonetheless. Here's what you do:

1. Write out a sample comment block in your code somewhere.
2. Insert `<#xyz#>` where you want a placeholder named 'xyz' to appear. (These are like parameter completion placeholders, so you can tab between them and overwrite them.)

For example:

```
/**
 * Method name: <#name#>
 * Description: <#description#>
 * Parameters: <#parameters#>
*/
```

1. Open up the right hand sidebar. In the bottom pane click on the two curly braces icon to bring up the snippets library.
2. Select and drag your text to the code snippets library.
3. It'll create a new one. Double click on it, click edit in the popup, and give it a completion shortcut (e.g. comblk for comment block.)

Now, when you type 'comblk' anywhere in your editors, the autocomplete popup appears and you can hit return to paste in the snippet. The first placeholder will be selected and you can start typing the method's name. Hit tab to switch to description, and so on.

Not ideal but it's better than nothing. Snippets are a nice idea that Apple haven't quite finished implementing yet.

Comment: thats cool. But i aspire to have some functionality like as explained next. When you click some of inbuilt Objective C methods, in quick view in right side bar, one can see all the respective details of the method. I would like that same shows for my methods also. Please tell me if possible.

Answer (score 125):

You can use shortcut for create header doc:

<kbd>⌘</kbd>  +  <kbd>⌥</kbd>  +  <kbd>/</kbd>

where 
 <kbd>⌘</kbd>  = Command 
 <kbd>⌥</kbd>  = Option (Alt on Windows compatible keyboards)

Comment: Does anybody know if it possible to switch to the multi-line comment with
`\**` and `*\ ` Instead of the single line ` \\\ ` ??

Comment: Should be ⌥ = Option:)

Answer (score 15):

**Xcode comment**

You can use a comment syntax to generate a doc:

- `Editor -> Structure -> Add Documentation`
- <kbd>⌘ command</kbd> <kbd>⌥ option</kbd> <kbd>/</kbd>
- ///<minimal_description>

Swift doc example:

```
/// <#Description#>
///
/// - Parameter param: <#param description#>
/// - Returns: <#return value description#>
/// - Throws: <#throws value description#>
func fun(param: String) throws -> String? {
    return false;
}
```

[image]

[Official Markup Formatting Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Xcode/Reference/xcode_markup_formatting_ref/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016497-CH2-SW1)

Answer (score 13):

1. Select your code for which you want to generate comment and press
   shortcut key

   **CMD + ALT + /**
2. Comment will be autogenerated for selected method.

Answer (score 8):

You can use this awesome plugin.

https://github.com/onevcat/VVDocumenter-Xcode

Answer (score 3):

Since Xcode 14 the shortcut depends on your chosen keyboard layout.
This shortcut for the English layout is (as before Xcode 14):
`⌘ command` + `⌥ option` + `/`

With a german keyboard layout you have to use this shortcut:
`⌘ command` + `⌥ option` + `ß`

If you are not sure you can check always check this in Xcode:

```
Editor -> Structure -> Add Documentation
```

Example:

```swift
func exampleMethod(parameter1: String, parameter2: String) -> Bool {  
}
```

Will be this:

```swift
<#Description#>
 - Parameters:
   - parameter1: <#parameter1 description#>
   - parameter2: <#parameter2 description#>
 - Returns: <#description#>
func exampleMethod(parameter1: String, parameter2: String) -> Bool {
}
```

**Important:**
You should always place your cursor in the method-name before using this shortcut.